# How to open Access with VBscript without having to put ODBC credentials everytime?

Tags: oracle, ms-access, vbscript, odbc

I'm pretty new to coding and have just started using VBscript for automating some reporting that I do.

And another project that I am working on is to write a VBscript code that opens Access, puts in my credentials (Username and password), run a Macro and then close Access.

I've been doing some researches regarding using a passthru query but had difficulties finding one that works for me and also setting up the connection for the pass thru query.

So far my code basically opens Access and Closes.

```
dim oaccess

set oaccess = createobject("access.application")

oaccess.visible=true
oaccess.usercontrol=true
oaccess.opencurrentdatabase "My_DATABASE"
oaccess.closecurrentdatabase
oaccess.quit
```

And the prompt screen that appears before I run whatever type of query or macro.

Has title of "Microsoft ODBC for Oracle Connect" 
, then has the empty areas where you put your User Name, Password and Server.
But in my case when it Opens already shows my Username and Server, so I just have to put the password in.

So if anyone has an idea in which way would be easier to do this I would extremely appreciate it.

Comment: Does this help https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/873231-run-autoexec-macro-where-odbc-password-required

Comment: Can you not save the username and password in the ODBC connection itself as defined in `odbcad32.exe`?